# How to select records that contain non-English characters on SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

How to select records that contain non-English characters on SQL Server?

The data column can contain combination of:

- English characters
- Special characters
- non-English characters

The filter should find records that contain at least one non-English character among other characters.

If record contains only English and / or special characters, it does not match the filter.

Data examples:

1. I liked كيكة التفاح بالمقلاة
2. τράπεζα τους φόρους και τον ΕΝΦΙΑ
3. I like தமிழ்
4. "Thank you" @stackoverflow.
5. https://stackoverflow.com

The filter has to fetch first 3 records.

Comment: What counts as "non-English", you don't see accented characters in native English (`é` or `ü`) words for example. What about a `æ` or `ß`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a whitelist of your English characters, then use UNICODE() function to loop the characters of the string to derterminate whether the string contains a character not in the whitelist, I prefer to create a UDF for this validation.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_Contains_Non_English_Char (
    @str_to_Validate NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @index INT
    DECLARE @len INT
    DECLARE @char NCHAR(1)

    SET @index = 1
    SET @len = LEN(@str_to_Validate)

    WHILE @index <= @len
    BEGIN
        SET @char = SUBSTRING(@str_to_Validate, @index, 1)
        SET @index = @index + 1

        -- You can use your own whitelist here
        IF UNICODE(@char) > 127 -- ASC II Chars
        --IF UNICODE(@char) > 255 -- Extended ASC II Chars
            RETURN 1

    END

    RETURN 0
END
GO

WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT N'I liked كيكة التفاح بالمقلاة' AS NOTE UNION ALL
    SELECT N'τράπεζα τους φόρους και τον ΕΝΦΙΑ' AS NOTE UNION ALL
    SELECT N'I like தமிழ்' AS NOTE UNION ALL
    SELECT N'"Thank you" @stackoverflow.' AS NOTE UNION ALL
    SELECT N'https://stackoverflow.com need to fetch first 3 records. please help on this.' AS NOTE 
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
WHERE dbo.fn_Contains_Non_English_Char(NOTE) = 1
```